# How to access this hashmap value 'id' in MuleExpression to compare it with queryparam?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule-esb

I have a hashmap payload in my flow, I want to compare its 'id' key with 'id' queryparameter to go to specific flow using a choice router. How to give this condition in MuleExpression for Choice router?

Here is the hashmap payload: [image: hashmap payload containing 4 records]

Answer (score 2):

`#[ payload.id == message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.id ]`